# CHATPDF API for Excel VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba, chatgpt-api

I have a challenge in the company to set up a contract control in Excel and I would like to integrate it with a CHATPDF account so that it pre-evaluates the document with some pre-selected questions.

There is an API [API CHATPDF](https://www.chatpdf.com/docs/api/backend), but I have no knowledge of python, and by definition excel add-ins are disabled in my company.

Is there any way to rewrite the code in VBA?

Examples of questions already selected:
1 - How long is the contract?
2 - What are the penalties in the event of non-compliance with the contract?
3 - ....

Example Excel spreadsheet structure:

| Customer | Date | Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | Cell 2 | Answer 1 | Answer 2 | Answer 3 |
| C2 | Cell 4 | Answer 1 | Answer 2 | Answer 3 |

I've tried uploading the pdf file but it always returns:

> Status:400
> Error: {"code":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"Could not read PDF"}

```
Sub EnviarRequisicaoHTTP()

    Dim http As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    ' Caminho do arquivo PDF
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = "C:\Users\martind3\001.pdf"

    ' URL da API
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://api.chatpdf.com/v1/sources/add-file"

    ' Chave da API
    Dim apiKey As String
    apiKey = "sec_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

    ' Configurando a solicitação HTTP
    http.Open "POST", url, False
    http.setRequestHeader "x-api-key", apiKey
       
    ' Adicionando o arquivo
    Dim formData As String
    formData = "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"

    ' Lendo o conteúdo do arquivo
    Dim fileContents() As Byte
    Dim fileNumber As Integer
    fileNumber = FreeFile
    Open filePath For Binary As fileNumber
    ReDim fileContents(LOF(fileNumber) - 1)
    Get fileNumber, , fileContents
    Close fileNumber

    ' Construindo a parte do arquivo
    Dim boundary As String
    boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
    Dim body As String
    body = "--" & boundary & vbCrLf
    body = body & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""; filename=""file.pdf""" & vbCrLf
    body = body & "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    body = body & StrConv(fileContents, vbUnicode) & vbCrLf
    body = body & "--" & boundary & "--" & vbCrLf

    ' Enviando a solicitação
    http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", formData
    http.send body

    ' Manipulando a resposta
    If http.Status = 200 Then
        MsgBox "Source ID: " & JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)("sourceId")
    Else
        MsgBox "Status: " & http.Status & vbCrLf & "Error: " & http.responseText
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You can most likely do this using VBA, but if you don't know any VBA then it's going to be a steep learning curve.

Comment: Sorry @TimWilliams, I tried to be more especific editing the question

Comment: This seems to work for me (returns status 200 and the expected json response), but I've not tried to query the file   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CXMQYF3pi-1I9uhmFnki8yGc0ida3tKb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams,  I used your code and it worked perfectly. Thank you! I posted the complete code as an answer.

Comment: Good to hear it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [@Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) code and it worked perfectly. I'm already getting the answers, now it's time to make the loops.

```
Option Explicit

Const KEY_CHATPDF As String = "sec_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Sub EnviarRequisicaoHTTP()
    
    Const BOUNDARY As String = "----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
    Const URL_ADDFILE As String = "https://api.chatpdf.com/v1/sources/add-file"
    
    Dim http As Object, filePath As String, url As String, formData As String
    Dim fileContents() As Byte, body As String, strm As Object
    
    filePath = Range("Arquivo").Value
    
    Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    http.Open "POST", URL_ADDFILE, False
    http.setRequestHeader "x-api-key", KEY_CHATPDF
    http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & BOUNDARY
    
    body = "--" & BOUNDARY & vbCrLf
    body = body & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""; filename=""file.pdf""" & vbCrLf
    body = body & "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    
    Set strm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    strm.Open
    strm.Position = 0
    strm.Type = 1 'binary
    strm.Write ToBytes(body)
    strm.Write ReadBinary(filePath)
    strm.Write ToBytes(vbCrLf & "--" & BOUNDARY & "--" & vbCrLf)
    strm.Position = 0
    
    http.send strm.Read()

    'Debug.Print http.Status
    'Debug.Print http.responsetext
    
    Range("Fonte").Value = http.responsetext

End Sub

Sub EnviarMensagemHTTP()

    Dim http As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    ' URL da API
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://api.chatpdf.com/v1/chats/message"


    ' Configurando a solicitação HTTP
    http.Open "POST", url, False
    http.setRequestHeader "referenceSources", True
    http.setRequestHeader "x-api-key", KEY_CHATPDF
    http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"

    ' Criando os dados a serem enviados
    Dim sourceId As String
    sourceId = Range("Fonte").Value

    Dim role As String
    role = "user"

    Dim content As String
    content = Range("Pergunta").Value

    Dim requestData As String
    requestData = "{""sourceId"": """ & sourceId & """, ""messages"": [{""role"": """ & role & """, ""content"": """ & content & """}]}"

    ' Enviando a solicitação
    http.send requestData
    
    'Debug.Print http.Status
    'Debug.Print http.responsetext
    
    Range("Resposta").Value = http.responsetext
    
End Sub


Private Function ReadBinary(strFilePath As String)
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 1
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile strFilePath
        ReadBinary = .Read
        .Close
    End With
End Function

Function ToBytes(str As String) As Variant
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Type = 2 ' text
        .Charset = "_autodetect"
        .WriteText str
        .Position = 0
        .Type = 1
        ToBytes = .Read
        .Close
    End With
End Function
```